# sys-kernel-debug, and logind service fail causing noticeable delay on logging in

Tags: debian, systemctl, proxmox, logind

### Background/Context

Im running a Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64(5.4.174-2-pve) virtualized server on a LVC container(proxmox stuff). Im really new to both debian(i tipically use arch linux which is roll and release) and proxmox as i barely touch on it(basically a family member of mine gave me a container for me to develop my website, and whatever i want on it)

I've started doing my stuff and it all went well, despite spending some time learning how the whole setting up mirrors for version thing and after some months i had a built website, along with the usual system attacks

I decided to help the family member that provided me the server by downloading somekind of pyhole to block ads, the thing was i wanted to do it through docker as i wasn't aware if it was gonna make a mess or not.

And i think it was when i downloaded docker and docker-compose when it all came down hill either that or due to the updates and upgrades i made during that time

### The visible problem

I started noticing that ssh took a lot more time to do the login stuff(like 5 seconds more). And i stress this enough it is **NOT** SSH itself as when i press the comand the usual motd shows up in a split second

Another thing i noticed is that:

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
```

Is printed twice, on proxmox console i think it shows the full message printed twice alternated. Like if the original message Was A B C, its prints A B A C B C.

### Diagnosis

Although i have some years(like 4) on arch linux, i use it for personal use, and... its a full installation instead of a container. So i never had to touch a lot on kernel stuff or other OS stuff.

Either way heres some ideas to share so hopefully i can get some help:

#### journalctl -b

```bash
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd-journald[59]: Journal started
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd-journald[59]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/c5b67cb2fb4c49678a4fd62f7e4a2b20) is 8.0M, max 116.3M, 108.3M free.
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD mount[65]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: cannot mount configfs read-only.
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd-journald[59]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/c5b67cb2fb4c49678a4fd62f7e4a2b20 is 2.371449s for 5 entries.
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd-journald[59]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/c5b67cb2fb4c49678a4fd62f7e4a2b20) is 80.0M, max 1.1G, 1.0G free.
Sep 04 13:05:51 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD apparmor.systemd[94]: Not starting AppArmor in container
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Load AppArmor profiles...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd-journald[59]: Forwarding to syslog missed 1 messages.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
Sep 04 13:05:52 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files being skipped.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being skipped.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Daily rotation of log files.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD cron[162]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD cron[162]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set up cgroupfs mounts....
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available being skipped.
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Sep 04 13:05:55 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD systemd[173]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD systemd[173]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD systemd[220]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:56 LinuxJD systemd[220]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[241]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[241]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[245]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[245]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[249]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD postfix[253]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Sep 04 13:05:57 LinuxJD systemd[249]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD postfix[253]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD postfix[253]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.2102.0]
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Permission denied.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: activation of module imklog failed [v8.2102.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
...(im cutting due to retries) 
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Permission denied.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: activation of module imklog failed [v8.2102.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
Sep 04 13:05:58 LinuxJD rsyslogd[168]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0" x-pid="168" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 04 13:05:59 LinuxJD sshd[299]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 04 13:05:59 LinuxJD sshd[299]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 04 13:05:59 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep 04 13:06:00 LinuxJD postmulti[301]: postsuper: fatal: scan_dir_push: open directory hold: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:06:00 LinuxJD postfix/postsuper[301]: fatal: scan_dir_push: open directory hold: Permission denied
Sep 04 13:06:01 LinuxJD postfix/postfix-script[302]: fatal: Postfix integrity check failed!
Sep 04 13:06:01 LinuxJD systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Sep 04 13:06:01 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 04 13:06:02 LinuxJD systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 13:06:02 LinuxJD systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 13:06:02 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
Sep 04 13:06:02 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Sep 04 13:06:02 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

So i proceeded to watch what some of the systemctl stuff was doing and what i got from all of this is that the failure of sys-kernel-config.mount, sys-kernel-debug.mount or **systemd-logind.service** are most likely causing various other services to fail, i tried to go around the internet but i only found unrelated answers

##### journalctl -u of login service

this are the only relevant lines that are printed into oblivion

```bash
Aug 23 13:04:14 LinuxJD systemd[132]: systemd-logind.service: **Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/proc: Permission denied**
Aug 23 13:04:14 LinuxJD systemd[132]: systemd-logind.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-logind: Permission denied
Aug 23 13:04:14 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Aug 23 13:04:14 LinuxJD systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 13:04:14 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.
```

as you can see its dated august 23rd,
*as a joke you can see how lazy i am to only start fixing it some days ago*
Before that the boot didnt display any errors although it did print some warnings saying Unknown lvalue  in section 'Service', ignoring. Variable names include ProtectProc, ProtectKernelLogs, etc...

##### journalctl -u sys-kernel-config.mount

```
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-08-22 10:01:37 WEST, ends at Sun 2022-09-04 13:23:49 WEST. --
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD mount[66]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: permission denied.
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-config.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-config.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to mount Kernel Configuration File System.
-- Boot 5e947e1d71c347de842d58ff83346b46 --
Aug 23 13:04:12 LinuxJD mount[67]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: cannot mount configfs read-only.
-- Boot 7cb1cef78bec4260b9b08de48728723f --
Aug 29 23:07:53 LinuxJD mount[67]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: cannot mount configfs read-only.
-- Boot f52c4a767b8343808ac8b2ae0c459494 --
Aug 30 17:03:10 LinuxJD mount[66]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: cannot mount configfs read-only.
-- Boot 3533ad0f42464deda95142c7eea10fc8 --
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD mount[69]: mount: /sys/kernel/config: cannot mount configfs read-only.
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-config.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-config.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to mount Kernel Configuration File System.
```

nothing to say here i was even unaware that there was some kind of mounting happening on sys/kernel/

##### journalctl -u sys-kernel-debug.mount

```
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-08-22 10:01:37 WEST, ends at Sun 2022-09-04 13:25:01 WEST. --
Aug 22 10:01:37 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 5e947e1d71c347de842d58ff83346b46 --
Aug 23 13:04:12 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 7cb1cef78bec4260b9b08de48728723f --
Aug 29 23:07:53 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot f52c4a767b8343808ac8b2ae0c459494 --
Aug 30 17:03:10 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 3533ad0f42464deda95142c7eea10fc8 --
Aug 30 17:16:20 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot adf79f39689b4cad9b0c5f25601a1e16 --
Aug 30 17:36:16 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 7670161016694d8cbebb490d8da76048 --
Aug 30 17:50:51 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 33d84ff5be5845fa87731c4ea0042c99 --
Sep 04 00:38:07 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot e2851d364555457a873de23656622b8b --
Sep 04 00:49:40 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot a7fff694cd6d4585b911d0ee40275b3c --
Sep 04 00:54:00 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
-- Boot 4fefd1bd372d47218eed549cd0044aa9 --
Sep 04 01:00:18 LinuxJD mount[55]: mount: /sys/kernel/debug: permission denied.
Sep 04 01:00:18 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-debug.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 04 01:00:18 LinuxJD systemd[1]: sys-kernel-debug.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 01:00:18 LinuxJD systemd[1]: Failed to mount Kernel Debug File System.
```

##### What about the others

If comments so advise i will post the logs but i feel as though these three are most likely causing a cascade of problems. for example modprobe just says its failing due to trying to being rerun too many times

### Attempts to fix it?

I've tried updating and upgrading stuff

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.pt.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye InRelease [10.5 kB]
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main arm64 Packages [15.8 kB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main amd64 Packages [77.8 kB]
Get:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye/main armhf Packages [17.7 kB]
```

heres the mirrors its hitting.
I've tried turning containerd off and on. I've tried removing pyhole container, I've tried some systemctl command `sudo systemctl log-level debug` hopping that it would give me some more text to fetch answers.
I've uninstalled docker and docker-compose as i was also having some problem with /proc stuff so i couldnt lauch anything.
I've tried rebooting bunch of times, and lastly i've turned some services related to nginx, php, posgresql, etc... off while boot to see if that was the problem.

The only thing that showed any kind of progression was... masking logind service, and although when i pressed enter i didnt fully know what the command did, it just seemed to temporarily symlink it no nowhere, which caused another bunch of problems but now there was no visible delay when logging in

i then proceeded to systemctl unmask systemd-logind and it bringed the issue back.

### TL;DR:

Theres a visible delay when loggin in to the server,
A mixture of systemd-logind, sys-kernel-config.mount, sys-kernel-debug.mount are in my eyes causing a bunch of services to fail.
A lot of errors always point to lack of permissions when mounting
Somehow the folder /proc is related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved!

Alright, although i wasn't able to fix everything yet im at a point where i consider the above to be fixed.

The problem is easier to solve than i thought, so if you wonder around here i guess you are just as clueless as me so im gonna try to go slow in order to prevent people from wasting time.

#### LoginD

LoginD was fixed by going to Proxmox dashboard, going to options on the left tab, double clicking on features and then enabling "Nesting"(im unsure if this contributed, either way i needed it for docker), and "keyctl". After rebooting systemd-logind service stopped reporting errors. This also caused a sharp reduction on accessing speed to tty console or ssh stuff

#### Kernel Stuff

This took me a bit more time, i had already came across [this github page](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/6676) but when he said:
`Ran into this on Proxmox and I resolved it by adding lxc.cap.drop: sys_rawio to my config and this is the result`
I was completely clueless, as until a few hours ago i had never messed around outside of my CT's tab.

Regardless i was eager to learn about proxmox and lxc containers and after messing around some commands i found lxc-config, doing lxc-config -l, shows you some "variables" one of these will be `lxc.lxcpath`

Doing `lxc-config lxc.lxcpath` will return the lxc path(duh), changing directory to it and listing the contents of it should(at least in my case) give you the various Containers and Virtual machines, im unsure if its a case of my Proxmox setup having numbers as CT's names or its just a version thing but in some troubleshooting videos/media i saw that instead of the id they had some kind of name.

Regardless i changed to the appropriate directory and then stopped the machine from running(i think this is required as i had some steps i will detail now rollback twice), and then edited the config file with nano
i appended:

```
lxc.cap.drop = sys_rawio
```

saved, rebooted the CT and... 2 services were now working these being sys-kernel-config.mount, sys-kernel-debug.mount im unshure what they are supposed to be responsible for, but i think the failing results from my container being unprivileged.

Im still kinda green about the second solution and im scared this will screw me over in the future so i will read the manual a bit more and if i find anything to be scared of i will update this answer appropriately.